# Menu versão mobile bootstrap não volta ao normal

Tags: php, bootstrap, menu

Tenho uma aplicação com um menu bootstrap, porém quando está na versão mobile que clico em algum link do menu, ele não volta ao normal (recua), fica da mesma forma como cliquei. Ele vai para a outra página, porém não volta ao normal.

Alguém já passou por isso?

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" style="margin-bottom: 0">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="dash">VOUCHER - Telemont</a>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
    <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
        <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                <li class="sidebar-search">
                    <div class="input-group custom-search-form">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Pesquisar..." id="disabledInput" disabled="">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" disableD>
                                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /input-group -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="dash"><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i> Início</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-group fa-fw"></i> Forcenedores<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="cadastro_fornec"> Cadastrar</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="consulta_fornecedor"> Consultar</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-ticket fa-fw"></i> Voucher<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="gerar_voucher">Gerar Autorização</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="acompanhamento_voucher">Atualizar Voucher</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="acompanhamento_nota_fiscal">Notas Fiscais</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="consulta_funcionarios">Funcionários</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="controle_voucher">Controle de Vouchers</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="cidade_base">Atualizar Cidade Base</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-building-o fa-fw"></i> Alojamento<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                    <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                        <li>
                            <a href="controle_alojamentos">Painel Geral</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="controle_termo_responsabilidade">Controle</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="relatorioGerencial"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw"></i> Relatório Gerencial</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Poste o código Tiago, ai conseguiremos analisar... vlw

Comment: @David, pronto.